# Make a copy of tenant in apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, apartment-gem

I am using apartment gem with PostgreSQL and I need to make a copy of already existing tenant with data. One way which I can think of one way is to collect all data from the tenant and then switch tenant and start creating record. Below is a small demonstration. Models are the list of models to be copied over.

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch!('destination')
models.each do |modal|
  eval("@#{modal.downcase} = #{modal}.all.collect{ |p| p.to_dh }")  
end
Apartment::Tenant.switch!('target')
models.each do |modal|
  eval("@#{modal.downcase}.each{ |p| #{modal}.create(p[:attributes], :without_protection => true) rescue p[:id]}")
end
models.each do |modal|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.reset_pk_sequence!(eval("#{modal}.table_name"))     
end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By default Apartment uses different schemas for different tenants.
So I would try to copy the schema via pg_dump and psql.

```
pg_dump -U <username> -p <port> -n <source> <database name> >> <dump filename>
# edit the dump.file
# CREATE SCHEMA <source>; => CREATE SCHEMA <target>;
# ALTER SCHEMA <source> OWNER TO <username>; => ALTER SCHEMA <target> OWNER TO <username>; 
psql -U <username> -p <port> -d <database> -f <dump filename>
```